# How can I call a function inside of a function?

Tags: javascript

How can I call the function inside of this function?

```
var video = function() {

    this.name = "Name of Video";
    this.desc = "Short Description of Video";
    this.long = "Long Description of Video";

    function metadata(){
        return {
            name : this.name,
            shortDescription : this.desc,
            longDescription : this.long
        };
    };

};
```

Comment: Looking at the votes and answers would suggest that many people are unaware what prototype is in JavaScript. Travis is the only one who mentions this. Also a constructor function should be capitalized as to indicate you should invoke it with new. More about prototype: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make it a method of the new object:

```
var video = function() {

    this.name = "Name of Video";
    this.desc = "Short Description of Video";
    this.long = "Long Description of Video";

    this.metadata = function(){
        return {
            name : this.name,
            shortDescription : this.desc,
            longDescription : this.long
        };
    };
};

var videoObject = new video();
videoObject.metadata();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't, other than within said function.

```
var video = function() {

    this.name = "Name of Video";
    this.desc = "Short Description of Video";
    this.long = "Long Description of Video";

    function metadata(){
        return {
            name : this.name,
            shortDescription : this.desc,
            longDescription : this.long
        };
    };
    metadata();

};
```

Comment: I want to be able to execute it from outside the main class/function any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, add it as a property of something that IS accessible outside. (other answers already demonstrate this)

Answer (score 4):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/GhjLN/)***

There are several options. A highly used approach is prototypes. A prototype will extend the object created with the functions defined on the prototype if the `new` keyword is used. You can take advantage of this to expose functions.

```
var video = function() {
 if( !(this instanceof video) ){//ensure that we always work with an instance of video
  return new video();   
 }

 this.name = "Name of Video";
 this.desc = "Short Description of Video";
 this.long = "Long Description of Video";
};
video.prototype.metadata = function(){
 return {
    name : this.name,
    shortDescription : this.desc,
    longDescription : this.long
 };
};
```

Now the options, it can be called directly:

```
console.log(video().metadata());
```

It can be used as a function call and then referenced

```
var v = video();
console.log(v.metadata());
```

Or it can be explicitly instantiated and then referenced

```
var vid = new video();
console.log(vid.metadata());
```

This ensures that basically all uses of the function end up with the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reach a nested function from the outside of the **first** outer wrapping-function **directly**:

See more info about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Therefore, an easy solution would be to use a function expression, attached to the returned object.

```
var video = function() {

    this.name = "Name of Video";
    this.desc = "Short Description of Video";
    this.long = "Long Description of Video";

    this.metadata = function(){
        return {
            name : this.name,
            shortDescription : this.desc,
            longDescription : this.long
        };
    };
};

new video().metadata();
```

Comment: You don't bother with any explanation?